# Counting a specific consecutive character with its occurrence position and length

Tags: awk, sed, perl, bioinformatics

I have a sequence file and want to count consecutive character "N" with its position of occurrence and the length
Say I have a file named `mySequence.fasta` like this:

```
>sequence-1
ATCGCTAGCATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTAGCATCATGCNNNNNNATACGCATCACANNNNNNNNNCgcatATCAC
```

and anticipated output should be like this:

```
Position 12 N 14
Position 38 N 6
Position 56 N 9
```

Kindly help me to solve this by `awk` or `sed` providing my file name `mySequence.fasta`

Comment: Does the Fasta file only contain sequences that is one line long or does a solution need to cover the case where a run of Ns wrap around the end of a line? Also, is there one or several sequences in the file?

Comment: In my objective have only one sequence in a file.  Further, its true that there are multi fasta sequence exists (one file containing many sequences starting with letter '>'. so, further possible solution for same task would be adding sequence identifier in output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do that with `awk`, whose `match()` that sets the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variable is quite useful for that:

```
<mySequence.fasta awk -v C=N '{
  i=0
  while (match($0, C "+")) {
    printf "Position %d %s %d\n", i+RSTART, C, RLENGTH
    i += RSTART+RLENGTH-1
    $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }}'
```

Or with `perl` using the `@-` and `@+` arrays that record the start and end of matches:

```
perl -ne 'printf "Position %d N %d\n", $-[0]+1, $+[0]-$-[0] while /N+/g'
```

Another slightly faster (at least with my version of `perl`) `perl` approach using the (*experimental*) `(?{...})` regexp operator:

```
perl -ne '0 while /N(?{$s=pos})N*(?{printf "Position %d N %s\n", $s, pos()-$s+1})/g'
```

Comment: Perl solution is faster than awk

Comment: @Budding-bioinformatician , for gawk, change the locale to C (`LC_ALL=C awk...`) to speed it up (after which I find performance are comparable to `perl`). I find that `mawk` is considerably faster than `gawk` or `perl` on that one. You can speed it up further if you hardcode the `N` in the code like in `perl`.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F '' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="N"&&!sPOS) sPOS=i;
   if (i==NF &&sPOS && $NF=="N"){LN++}; if($i=="N" &&sPOS && i<NF) {LN++}
   else if(sPOS) {printf("Position %d N %d\n", sPOS, LN); LN=sPOS=0} }
}' infile.txt
```

As all of `awk` implementation doesn't support empty FS (`-F ''`), below is the revised script to be compatible:

```
awk -F'N' '{sPOS=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==""&&!sPOS) sPOS=(i-1)+length($(i-1));
    if($i=="" &&sPOS && NF!=i) {LN++} 
    else if(sPOS) {printf("Position %d N %d\n", sPOS, ++LN); sPOS+=LN+length($i); LN=0} }
}' infile.txt
```

Sample input:

```
>sequence-1
ATCGCTAGCATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTAGCATCATGCNNNNNNATACGCATCACANNNNNNNNNCgcatATCACNN
N
AN
NNA
```

The result is:

```
Position 12 N 14
Position 38 N 6
Position 56 N 9
Position 75 N 2
Position 1 N 1
Position 2 N 1
Position 1 N 2
```